# c# Form Collection Values to List of Int

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-4, formatting, formcollection

I have a Form Collection in my C# MVC4 application. In `index[0]` of this collection there is a string that will always be formatted like `"10=on&13=on&15=on"`; the only difference being the number of `#=on` in the string.

I want to pull each of the numbers from this string and add them to a list of ints.  What would be the simplest method of doing this? Is Regex required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var nums = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value)
          .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

> What would be the simplest method of doing this?

I would use a custom model binder:

```
public class MyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var request = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Params;
        var keys =
            from key in request.Keys.Cast<string>()
            where request[key] == "on"
            select key;
        var onValues = new List<int>();
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            int value;
            if (int.TryParse(key, out value))
            {
                onValues.Add(value);
            }
        }

        return onValues.ToArray();
    }
}
```

and then a controller action like that:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction([ModelBinder(typeof(MyModelBinder))]int[] values)
{
    return View();
}
```

Now you could simply send the following request to this controller action and the custom model binder will do the job:

```
/SomeAction?10=on&13=on&15=on
```

> Is Regex required?

Nooooooooooooooooooooo.

Answer (score 0):

The string in question looks like a query string so one approach would be to use [`System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring.aspx) to get a `NameValueCollection` from the string. Then enumerate the keys and parse them to get integers.

```
var collection = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("10=on&13=on&15=on");

foreach (var key in collection.Keys.Cast<string>())
{
    int i;
    if (int.TryParse(key, out i))
    {
        // add i to list of ints
    }
}
```